How to make Asiatic Lily bulbs sprout?
I bought 5 Asiatic lily bulbs on Amazon about 40 days ago. All of them were healthy. 3 were sprouted. The new stem of one of the sprouted ones broke. 40 days later these 3 bulbs (2 unsprouted and one with stem broken) are still healthy but have not sprouted yet! Is this normal? I have planted them in cocopeat so I can check up on them. The avg temperature around here nowadays is 30ºC/86ºF. Currently I am keeping the pots in direct sunlight. And water them as soon as the cocopeat around bulbs start drying out. Should I do something different to make them sprout faster?

Does anybody know anything about this?
